# How do I retrieve an async value for a restangular parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, cas, restangular

I need to retrieve a value from an async service to add as a parameter to every rest call. The casService.getProxyTicket() is an $http call...

I have the following code :-

```
myFactories.factory('myFactory', [
    'Restangular'
    , 'casService'
    , function (Restangular
        , casService) {
        return Restangular.withConfig(function (config) {
            config.setBaseUrl('https://host:port/somecontext/rest');
            config.addFullRequestInterceptor(function (element
                , operation
                , route
                , url
                , headers
                , params
                , httpConfig) {
```

... What do I need to do here?

```
                casService.getProxyTicket(url).then(function(st){
                    console.log('proxyTicket = ' + st.data.ticket);
                });

                params.ticket = ?????? <= st.data.ticket
```

...

```
                return {
                    element: element
                    , headers: headers
                    , params: params
                    , httpConfig: httpConfig
                }
            });
        }).service('myCollection');
    }]
);
```

...thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my lack of understanding coming from a backend developer's background...

This can/should NOT be done this way! I was trying to make the call to get a proxy ticket synchronous.... DON'T DO IT!

What I did was to rearrange my code thus ...

```
function readItem(id) {
    var endpoint = myFactory.one(id);
    return casService.getProxyTicket(endpoint.getRestangularUrl())
        .then(function (response) {
            return endpoint.get({ticket: response.data.proxyTicket});
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.plain();
        });
}
```

...works like a charm!